# Excel List iteration

Tags: python, list, xlwt

I am working on a text search project. I have 2 lists.

```
a = ['ibm','dell']
b =['strength','keyword']##this is a list of keywords given by the user
```

Now i create combinations for searching google.

```
lst = list(itertools.product(a, b))
```

What i need help on is below:
using the code i will search for the text using different keywords and their lemma. After that I need to write the searched text to an excel file. I need to create worksheets with the names in list A and write it only the searched text in different worksheets. I am not able to figure. below is part of my code.

```
def getarticle(url,n):
    final =[]
    regex ='(.*).pdf'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    if re.match(pattern,url) is not None:
        text = pdf_to_text(url)
        final.append('')
        final.append(url)
        final.append(text)
        New_file = open((('text' + str((round(random.random(),2))) + '.txt')),'w+')
        New_file.write(smart_str(unicode(text,'utf-8')))
        New_file.close()
    else:
        br = mechanize.Browser()
        br.set_handle_robots(False)
        br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Chrome')]
        html = br.open(url).read()
        titles = br.title()
        readable_article= Document(html).summary()
        readable_title = Document(html).short_title()
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(readable_article)
        Final_Article = soup.text
        final.append(titles)
        final.append(url)
        final.append(Final_Article)
        raw = nltk.clean_html(html)
        cleaned = re.sub(r'& ?(ld|rd)quo ?[;\]]', '\"', raw)
        tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(raw)
        lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
        t = [lmtzr.lemmatize(t) for t in tokens]
        text = nltk.Text(t)
        word = words(n)
        find = ' '.join(str(e) for e in word)
        search_words = set(find.split(' '))
        sents = ' '.join([s.lower() for s in text])
        blob = TextBlob(sents.decode('ascii','ignore'))
        matches = [map(str, blob.sentences[i-1:i+2])     # from prev to after next
                for i, s in enumerate(blob.sentences) # i is index, e is element
                if search_words & set(s.words)]
        return  ''.join (str(y).replace('& rdquo','').replace('& rsquo','') for y in matches)
```

This returns the text now i need to write to excel files which i am unable to code.

Comment: I think I've adjusted your code block correctly. Please make sure the indention is how you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

As far as writing text out to a file Excel can read is concerned, ou might want to look at Python's [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library, which provides lots of useful .csv manipulation tools.